# How does RabbitMQ message TTL can be tested in an application without changing it from codebase

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, ttl

I have a problem regarding RabbitMQ message TTL. In my application I'm setting message TTL as 1 month from the code level . In a case where I need to check whether TTL thing works how can I do that without doing modification in the code level.(I haven't set any consumers so messages will stay in the Queue and I can see that through the RabbitMQ management plugin web UI)

Ex: I publish the message by setting TTL as the number of milliseconds per month. Then can I go change the system time of host machine to one month back and see messages getting discarded?? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test by setting ttl to 5 minutes and then changed the system date time advanced it by 10 mins.

There is a clock on top right corner of Rabbit MQ Admin interface so you can see the current system datetime changes.

The message was removed from the queue so it is possible to test your scenario.